# How to solve Memory Leaks?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I don't want to use `@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")`. How to solve the correct way to do? `(Do not place Android context classes in static fields)`

"DataConnect"

```
public class DataConnect {

    public static DialogPlus dialog;

    public static void showDialog(Context context) {
        dialog = DialogPlus.newDialog(context)
                .setContentHolder(new ViewHolder(R.layout.content))
                .create();
                //
        dialog.show();
        // 
    }
}
```

And then, when I run MainActivity, `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.orhanobut.dialogplus.DialogPlus.isShowing()' on a null object reference`. How to call dialog variable from another class by correct way?

"MainActivit.java"

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a static DialogPlus, and any context subclasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use static when holding android activities/fragments or any views because you will leak them.

If you want to create your dialog in a helper class you can do it this way:

```
public static DialogPlus showDialog(Context context) {
        DialogPlus dialog = DialogPlus.newDialog(context)
                .setContentHolder(new ViewHolder(R.layout.content))
                .create();
                //
        dialog.show();
        return dialog;

    }
```

And somewhere in your activity you can do:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DialogPlus dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dialog = DataConnect.showDialog(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ClapaLucianI don't want to showDialog onCreate(). Because showDialog is called when user click Button.

Comment: Well, u can add it wherever, i just added it oncreate for simplicity :)

Comment: if it doesn't add `dialog = DataConnect.showDialog(this);`,dialog is not working. Even dialog.isShowing(), it doesn't dismiss - direct go to super.onBackPressed()

Comment: @StevenPhyo you have to do that to have a reference to your dialog otherwise in onBackPressed your dialog will be null that's why is not working